# Get all SharePoint files and folders of a drive using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

My problem is: if I call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root/children` all I get are the top-level items of that drive.

How can I achieve to get **all the subfolders and files** of the drive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There's no endpoint to get all items in a drive with every file from every subfolder at once.**

Below endpoint maps to a test library MyDoc3.

```
/sites/siteid/drives/{drive-id}
```

Then, below endpoint use to get children of `FolderA` in MyDoc3.

```
/sites/siteid/drives/{drive-id}/root:/FolderA:/children
```

Comment: Is there any endpoint I can use to get all files and folders in MyDoc3, not only FolderA? That's what I'm seeking.

Comment: I checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0 and did research&test, not find such endpoint. You may do this recursively or use SharePoint rest api https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call

Comment: There isn't a simple way to grab an entire document library as a flat list (i.e. every file, from every folder, all at once). You need to "walk the folder tree" an compile the list of files. You can determine which item is a Folder vs a File by looking for a `folder` property (its a folder) vs a `file` property (its a file).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur if I call `/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields` I get a bunch of items and a `@odata.nextLink` property to make the next call. Is it a better choice?

Comment: If you're just looking for a collection ListItems, yes. This won't give you the same file metadata of a DriveItem however.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur an issue I'm facing with the results of ListItems is the delete request doesn't move the item to the Recycle Bin as it happens with DriveItem. Is there any way to delete an item using ListItems and get it moved to Recycle Bin? Also, I'm not sure if ListItems show folders or just files. Could you tell me this as well?

Comment: I believe the `ListItem` collection will only contain files but I'd recommend testing this. It's been a while since I've worked with them. As for deleting, the only way to move them to the recycling bin is to delete the `DriveItem`. You'll need to pull the `DriveItem` identifier and issue a delete to the drive instead of the list.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur is there any way to get the `DriveItem` identifier from the `ListItem` metadata?

Comment: Yes, `DriveItem` and `ListItem` have a relationship: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Comment: You may need to `$expand=DriveItem`

Comment: @MarcLaFleur you're awesome! Thanks Marc!

Comment: @Lee_MSFT I can accept your answer if you edit it with the information there's no endpoint to get at once all items in a drive with every file from every subfolder.

Comment: Is there a way to create sub folder? with graph api i am able to create folder at root level, but cant find a way to create child folder like windows directories.

Answer (score 8):

I found that the below endpoint retrieves all files and folders in a library. The result will be paged, with a standard page size of 200 items.

```
/drives/{drive-id}/list/items
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Lee. There is an enpoint. More or less maybe a hack:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[driveId]/root/search(q='')
```

This Call will provide any Files within a Drive.

You can even search within a subpath:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DRIVEID]/items/[ITEMID/search(q='')
```

But this will NOT return any Images or visual Content.