# Is there a rest call to get the item id for a document on SharePoint online or on drive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I need to obtain the document's information uploaded on SharePoint online. But I cannot use item id as it's not possible to keep a track of pre- uploaded documents.
Is there a rest call that can give the list of all the documents 
Present on a drive/folder on SharePoint online or one drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a rest call to get the item id for a document on SharePoint
>   online or on drive?

For this issue , you can retrieve the metadata for a DriveItem in a Drive by file system path or ID. For details please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online).

> Is there a rest call that can give the list of all the documents
>   Present on a drive/folder on SharePoint online or one drive?

For this issue,you have the below api to get all the files inside a folder. For details, please refer to this [case](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call).

```
<YouDomainServer>/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<relativepath>)/Files
```

In addition ,you can also use Graph API to get user's one drive data in SharePoint. You can refer to this [blog](https://blog.dodhia.co/get-users-one-drive-data-in-sharepoint-using-graph-api/) and [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496616/get-all-sharepoint-files-and-folders-of-a-drive-using-microsoft-graph-api) to get help.