# Mircrosoft Graph API: List all DriveItems in a drive : badRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the drive of my sharepoint using the following which returns the drive and its ID etc

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive
```

However the below call  returns a "Bad Request, url specified is invalid". Has anyone got any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive/items
```

Comment: edited original post with that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the root folders like this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/drive/root/children
```

Note that  `mysite/drive` is the default drive.

You can use

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/drives/{driveId}/root/children
```

to identify the specific driveId.

**There's no endpoint to get all items in a drive with every file from every subfolder at once.**

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496616/get-all-sharepoint-files-and-folders-of-a-drive-using-microsoft-graph-api) for your reference.

Comment: ah yes they are pretty much duplicates I had forgotten I posted it